# Change field Purpose in Reservation form

Tags: lotus-notes

I just wonder if it is possible to change the formula of the field Purpose in the reservation form.

By default, the formula looks like;

@If(@IsAvailable(Purpose); Purpose; Topic)

I want to replace what is displayed in the form in order to hide the purpose for people not invited to the reservation. For example;

@If(@IsAvailable(Purpose); "This is a standard text"; Topic)

The field Purpose is editable so I intend to add a new Field, dspPurpose that will be computed for display, and hide the real Purpose Field and use the second formula.

My question is, will this have any side effetcs?

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you ask, if you can change the formula: Of course you can... If you ask, if this will have an effect for example on mailed- in invitations: most possibly not...

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, I will change it, I do wonder if it is possible without any side-effects. Hide the real Purpose field, add a new field that is computet for display only, and use the new formula in the new field. As far as I can see, it will not tamper the content of the real Purpse field and then it should not have any side effetcs?

Comment: You have to change the view columns to show the new purpose field as well, and of course it is only "security by obscurity" as the user can always see the content of the purpose- item by just Pressing Alt + Enter and inspect the properties of the document... But at least there will not be unwanted side effects as far as i can see.

Comment: Thank you Torsten, when I checked the views, or really I did a search on the Purpose field in the database, it did not show up in any views. Document properties is known and we do not care about that. But, I just realized another question. If a hide the new dspPurpose field when editing, and hide the real Purpose field for reading, who can then edit the real Purpose field? Only the people invited?